# How to install qt 5.6.0 in a computer without network access

Tags: qt

I've downloaded the offline version of `QT SDK 5.6.0` and when I  tried it, it requires me to input the account information, but in that computer, I have no network access.

[image]

Is there any possible way to install it in this computer?

Comment: Are sure that installer requires sing-up? In my case, you can omit singing and press skip button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are sure that installer requires sing-up? In my case, you can omit singing and press skip button: 
[image]

Comment: Oh...My carelessness! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version of the offline installer there is no longer a skip button.
But the question about the account information can be skipped by setting the proxy to `0.0.0.0:123`

Comment: This is the way to go, but the answer needs a bit more clarification. You have to set the proxy through Internet Explorer (Settings -> Internet options ->Connections -> LAN Settings, In the window that pops up, enable the Proxy server checkbox and enter 0.0.0.0 to address field and 123 to port field). After the proxy is configured, run Qt installer. And once installed, revert these proxy settings, or else you will have no internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your installer is for Enterprise. You need an active license to download/install Enterprise edition of Qt therefore you need to sign in.

As [AnatolyS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2126582/anatolys) pointed out - you can skip signing-in in the Community (free) version of the Qt.

Comment: Thank you! It's my carelessness that I didn't see the `skip` button as shown in @AnatolyS's answer.